Integration and boundedness of integral Proof and Statement
I am not sure if this is a standard theorem, since I can't find a name for it: Suppose that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R, m)$ where $m$ is the standard lebesgue measure. Then for every $\epsilon >0$, there is an $R>0$ such that
$$\int_{|x|>R} |f| <\epsilon$$
I tried proving it in the following manner:
Suppose there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $R>0$,
$$\int_{|x|>R} |f| \geq \epsilon$$
Note that
$$|f(x)|\mathbb{1}_{ \{|x|>\} R} (x) \to 0 \text{ as } R\to \infty$$
almost anywhere since $\{|x|=\infty\}$ is a null set (it's a singleton). By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we get that
$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\{|x|>R\}} |f(x)| dx = 0 \geq \epsilon$$
yielding a contradiction.
I would like to know if this result has a standard name and whether my proof needs any revision?

${|x| = \infty}$ is empty, not a singleton. No real number has infinite absolute value.
